# Android - Hide Label on Switch Widget

Tags: android, widget, switch-statement

I'm adding a Switch widget to my screen but I do not want the label to show. If I set android:text to an empty string, or don't set it at all, there is empty gap to the left of the widget and tapping the gap causes the widget to toggle.

Does anyone know how to hide the label portion of a switch? Thank you in advance for your help.

```
<Switch
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:text=""
  android:textOn="@string/switch_text_yes"
  android:textOff="@string/switch_text_no"
  android:checked="false" />
```

Comment: The "empty space" is the alternative position if the switch. You cannot get rid of it without removing the ability to visually distinguish between positions. If all you want is a white rectangle, use an `ImageView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I discovered it has something to do with the fact I am using TableLayout. The Switch (although not the actual visible button) was expanding to be as wide as the entire cell even though `android:layout_width` was set to `wrap_content`. The visible button was its normal size on the right and the gap on the left was as big as necessary to take up the rest of the cell.

The answer is to set `android:layout_gravity="left"` on the Switch.

Answer (score 1):

The gap that you are seeing is the switchPadding - minimum space between the switch and caption text.

There is an XML attribute switchPadding (in Switch and SwitchCompat view) that you can set to 0dp to remove the gap.

Docs: [SwitchCompat.setSwitchPadding](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/widget/SwitchCompat#setSwitchPadding(int))

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by first deleting the value in "text" setting the "layout_width" to "wrap_content", setting the "layout_gravity" to include "left" and adjusting the "switchMinWidth" parameter to make it longer.